# Anet A8 - SkyNet3D freezes randomly at boot

Tags: marlin, anet-a8, skynet3d

I have a problem with my Anet A8. It is a little strange because it does not always happen.

When I turn on my printer, it freezes on boot in the second splash screen.

If I turn off and turn on several times, the printer works OK.

The printer firmware is:

- *SKYNET 3D - V2.1 - BASED ON MARLIN RC7-BUGFIX - FOR ANET 3D PRINTERS*

It was modified by me but I promise that I did not touch the boot section.

Could the Anet A8 motherboard be dying ? (before this issue it worked perfectly)

- **Update 1**:

  - I am changing some wires (power supply and hot bed). I think it has improved...
    In my opinion, I think that is better change all wires...
- **Update 2**: Some wires were black :-( (I changed them and the printer run well)

Comment: Skynet3D is an [obsolete firmware](/a/5949/5740)! Please install a more recent firmware, e.g. Marlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Anet A8 is a low end printer which works better after installing a better (read safer) than stock firmware (stock firmware does not have thermal runaway protection which is considered to be a hazard). It is good that you flashed another firmware that does have thermal runaway protection.

The electronics of the Anet A8 are also questionable, the stock connectors are not rated for their task and wires could have been of better quality and thickness.

Now that your older SkyNet3D firmware does not boot properly anymore, it would be time to check all the leads, possibly use new wires of proper gauge and flash a new version of a more recent firmware. SkyNet3D has been forked from [Marlin Firmware](http://marlinfw.org/) and is no longer maintained as all functionality has been [implemented for Anet printers](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/tree/1.1.x/Marlin/example_configurations/Anet) in the [Marlin sources](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin).

If your printer still is giving you problems then when booting, a new set of electronics (e.g. board and steppers) would help out.